# Is there way to mock pojo other then setting values manually in mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

consider a method returns class A in my service,

```
public List<A> method(){
A a=B.method_b();
List<A> list=new ArrayList<>();
for(A aa:a){
A classA=new A();
classA.setVal1(aa.getVal1());
list.add(classA);
}
        return list;
    }
```

My pojo class

```
class A{
private int val1;
private int val2;
.
.
.
.
private int val10;
//setter and getter 
}
```

so in test case ,i wrote as

```
@Mock
B b;
@Test
public void check(){
 Mockito.when(b.method_b())
        .thenReturn(return_A());
}
private A return_A(){
A a=new A();
a.setVal1(1);
.
.
.
a.setVal10(10);
}
```

Here everything is working fine .Code coverage is also fine.But my question is ,is there any possible way to avoid above private method that returns class A by using mockito ?

Comment: You shouldn't need mockito. Just extend `B` and override `method_b()` to return your custom value.

Comment: @shmosel bad idea! what id B is an interface and gets new methods over time? You constantly have to change old unittests...

Comment: No, i just want to avoid manually providing setters coz,even if i miss a single setter my test case fails .

Comment: @TimothyTruckle My assumption was that `B` was a concrete class. Perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: @shmosel even if so, when using a mocking framework you can later change `B` to be an interface without changing the test. This is an important feature of unit tests!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a unittest you define the behavior of your class depending on input.
This means you have to specify this input. There is no way around it.

There are different ways to do that.

one way it to configure the DTO the way you did.

Another way is to generate the input data. But this has some downsites:
 - you still need a method (or class) to do that,
 - it makes your test harder to read and understand,
 - it introduces failure possibilities in your test making it less reliable,

One more way  is to set only those values needed for the current test in the `//arrange` section of your test method:

```
@Mock
B b;
@Test
public void check(){
  // arrange
  Mockito.when(b.method_b())
        .thenReturn(return_A());
  A a=new A();
  // values to be used by cut in this test
  a.setVal1(1);
  a.setVal3(3); 

  // act
  // assert 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Timothy Truckle .So, you are saying i can set the values needed for the current test and there is no other options to avoid manually setting setter values.

Comment: @Hemalatha *"So, you are saying i can set the values needed for the current test"* yes. - *"and there is no other options to avoid manually setting setter values"* I say "there are no *useful* other options..."

Comment: I understood .Thank you very much @Timothy Truckle

Answer (score 0):

I came across this https://devskiller.github.io/jfairy/. This may useful for providing setter values if don't want to set values manually (hardcoded values).

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [PODAM](https://mtedone.github.io/podam/)

Add the gradle dependency

```
testImplementation 'uk.co.jemos.podam:podam:7.2.5.RELEASE'
```

How to use it ?

```
PodamFactory podamFactory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
Student student = podamFactory.manufacturePojo(Student.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very happy to use [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) for .NET.

You can check [JFixture](https://github.com/FlexTradeUKLtd/jfixture) for Java.

I think it is what you want.